# Intermittent PostgreSQL error: missing FROM-clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, rake, pg

I have a Rails app running on Heroku which intermittently throws Postgres 'missing FROM-clause' errors from UPDATEs executed by a Rake task.

An example UPDATE statement is:

```
UPDATE "temp_stats_values" 
    SET "number" = 66, 
        "average" = 0, 
        "percentage" = 0, 
        "num_out_of" = 0, 
        "updated_at" = '2013-01-12 11:43:40.067530' 
WHERE "temp_stats_values"."id" = 1330
```

And the error thrown is:

`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "temp_stats_values"`

The thing is, I don't know why it's expecting a FROM clause for this SQL when there clearly isn't another table involved. Also, the fact that it seems to be intermittent is pretty confusing. The errors, when they happen, are being caught by Airbrake.

Anyway, if anyone has any good ideas I'd be very grateful.

---

**UPDATE**

Example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/9aa0d/2) which works as expected

Comment: Can you give the table definition and some test data? Prefferably in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12).

Comment: Good idea Igor, unfortunately it works as expected

Comment: I don't know rake, but a shot in the dark: add a semicolon? Or a correlation name (alias) and use it.

Comment: Oh, that could just be the thing to fix it. Good thinking. The trouble is, that SQL is currently the result of a Rails update_attributes call via the PG gem but I guess I could roll my own as I'm liberally scattering 'Coding Horror SQL' throughout the rest of this particular Rake task...

Comment: Do you get the parameters from "somewhere" and assemble the full statement? Maybe sometimes the parameters contain "junk" (aka SQL injection) and thus the statement becomes invalid. Try to use "prepared statements" instead (don't know the term in Ruby)

Comment: Good thought but it's all pretty structured, without any user input. The example above is one that actually failed when run on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, without any intervention these errors magically dried up, just like they magically started happening in the first place. Spooky. Anyway, thanks to all who commented.